# setState long execution when managing large amount of records

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to solve a problem that happens in react app. In one of the views (components) i have a management tools that operate on big data. Basically when view loads i have `componentDidMount` that triggers ajax fetch that downloads array populated by around 50.000 records. Each array row is an object that has 8-10 key-value pairs.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { List } from "react-virtualized";
import Select from "react-select";

class Market extends Component {
  state = {
    sports: [], // ~ 100 items
    settlements: [], // ~ 50k items
    selected: {
      sport: null,
      settlement: null
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSports();
    this.getSettlements();
  }

  getSports = async () => {
    let response = await Ajax.get(API.sports);

    if (response === undefined) {
      return false;
    }

    this.setState({ sports: response.data });
  };

  getSettlements = async () => {
    let response = await Ajax.get(API.settlements);

    if (response === undefined) {
      return false;
    }

    this.setState({ settlements: response.data });
  };

  save = (key, option) => {
    let selected = { ...this.state.selected };
    selected[key] = option;
    this.setState({ selected });
  };

  virtualizedMenu = props => {
    const rows = props.children;
    const rowRenderer = ({ key, index, isScrolling, isVisible, style }) => (
      <div key={key} style={style}>
        {rows[index]}
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <List
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        width={300}
        height={300}
        rowHeight={30}
        rowCount={rows.length || 1}
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
      />
    );
  };

  render() {
    const MenuList = this.virtualizedMenu;

    return (
      <div>
        <Select
          value={this.state.selected.sport}
          options={this.state.sports.map(option => {
            return {
              value: option.id,
              label: option.name
            };
          })}
          onChange={option => this.save("sport", option)}
        />
        <Select
          components={{ MenuList }}
          value={this.state.selected.settlement}
          options={this.state.settlements.map(option => {
            return {
              value: option.id,
              label: option.name
            };
          })}
          onChange={option => this.save("settlement", option)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem i am experiencing is that after that big data is downloaded and saved to view state, even if i want to update value using select that has ~100 records it takes few seconds to do so. For example imagine that `smallData` is array of 100 items just `{ id: n, name: 'xyz' }` and `selectedFromSmallData` is just single item from data array, selected with html select.

making a selection before big data loads takes few `ms`, but after data is loaded and saved to state it suddenly takes 2-4 seconds.

What would possibly help to solve that problem (unfortunately i cannot paginate that data, its not anything i have access to).

Comment: Please show your `render` method. You probably need to move the parts which render `state.bigData` and/or `state.smallData` to a separate PureComponent.

Comment: Did you try doing it without your update function ? Just with this.setState ? It might isolate the problem

Comment: i updated my question with source code, hope it helps, i tried to avoid save method, i tried to move the selected value directly to state, this doesnt change anything, as soon as big data downloads every saving takes seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map()` creates a new array on every render. To avoid that you have three options:

1. store `state.sports` and `state.settlements` already prepared for `Select`
2. every time you change `state.sports` or `state.settlements` also change `state.sportsOptions` or `state.settlementsOptions`
3. use `componentDidUpdate` to update `state.*Options`:

The third option might be easier to implement. But it will trigger an additional rerender:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.sports !== this.state.sports) {
      this.setState(oldState => ({sportsOptions: oldState.sports.map(...)}));
    }
    ...
  }
```

Your `onChange` handlers are recreated every render and may trigger unnecessary rerendering of `Select`. Create two separate methods to avoid that:

```
saveSports = option => this.save("sport", option)
...
render() {
  ...
  <Select onChange={this.saveSports}/>
  ...
}
```

You have similar problem with `components={{ MenuList }}`. Move this to the state or to the constructor so `{MenuList}` object is created only once. You should end up with something like this:

```
    <Select
      components={this.MenuList}
      value={this.state.selected.settlement}
      options={this.state.settlementsOptions}
      onChange={this.saveSettlements}
    />
```

If this doesn't help consider using the default `select` and use a `PureComponent` to render its options. Or try to use [custom](https://react-select.com/components) `PureComponents` to render parts of the `Select`.

Also check [React-select is slow when you have more than 1000 items](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3128)

Comment: thank you mate, indeed i got inspired by your suggestions and it turned out that headline of your answer was to blame the most. avoiding `map( () => ` almost entirely eliminated delay, i am now pre-making these options after download of data is complete, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The size of the array shouldn't be a problem, because only the reference is stored in the state object, and react doesn't do any deep equality on state.
Maybe your render or componentDidUpdate iterates over this big array and that causes the problem.
Try to profile your app if this doesn't help.